# Dragging: Replacement of the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, drag-and-drop, tinymce

I got a webpage with some html elements including a textarea and an embedded contenteditable iframe (a rte).

Using this code i manage to catch the draggesture event on the main page and set the text/html-data

```
jQuery(document).bind('draggesture', function(event){                   
    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', 'my_data');
});
```

Now, when dropping in a textarea on the main page 'my_data' gets dropped.
Dropping in the contenteditable iframe drops 'my_data' too.

But i got three issues here that i do not understand:

**1.** Binding this kind of handler to the iframes document works. I set the events data analog to the above code, but it does not work. When i drag it inside the iframe or to the textarea on the main page 'my_data' does not get inserted, but the original selected content. **What can i do to set 'my_data'?**

**2.** I tried to modify/set the data using the drop event in the iframe and the main page:

```
jQuery(ed.getDoc()).bind('drop', function(event){
  event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/html',  'my_data');
});
```

But i get a javascript error on both documents (main page and iframe) :  "Modifications are not allowed for this document".
**Why do i get this error? Is there a workaround for this?**
Looks like pimvdb got an explantion for this.

**3.** When selecting `<p>some text</p><hr><p>some text</p>` from the main page and dragging this into the contenteditable iframe nothing gets inserted when i set 'my_data' (on Draggesture) using the first code example from above. Dragging into the textarea works. **Does anyone know what gets wrong here?** (problem does not occur using chrome!)

**EDIT:** Here is a jsFiddle demo to play around and understand the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/R2rHn/5/

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle demo?

Comment: see my edited post - i added a jsFiddle demo

Answer (score 1):

You are using `draggesture` but `dragstart` works.

Second, it does not make sense to set the `dataTransfer` data on `drop`, because the drag "package" has already arrived by then. It's being destroyed after the drop, so why would you like to change it at that point?

I cleaned your fiddle to get straight what was happening so as to be able to solve it, and this is the result. It seems to work on Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/R2rHn/7/

```
tinyMCE.init({
   mode : "exact",
   elements : "content",
   skin : "o2k7",
   skin_variant : "silver",

   setup : function(ed) {
     ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
       var iframe = ed.getDoc();

       jQuery(iframe).bind('dragstart', function(event){
         event.originalEvent
              .dataTransfer
              .setData('text/plain', 'modified_content_from_iframe');
       });
     });
   },

});

jQuery(document).bind('dragstart', function(event){          event.originalEvent
         .dataTransfer
         .setData('text/html',  'my_data_html');

    event.originalEvent
         .dataTransfer
         .setData('text/plain', 'my_data_plain');
});
```

Comment: +1 Works fine in chrome, but not in firefox. I need a firefox solution because our customer is using Firefox. Unfortunatly modifying drag data when dragging from the contenteditable iframe to the textarea does not work using FF5 & FF6. Using FF the behaviour is still the same.

Comment: @Thariama: I'm not sure about Firefox. Perhaps Firefox has not full support and certain bugs. Drag and Drop is HTML5, so it might not be fully working yet.

Comment: @Thariama: I've not been able to find a workaround I'm afraid. I'll leave my answer but am interested in the solution if someone else finds one.

Comment: @Thariama : I have got the same problem now of `Modifications are not allowed for this document` . Can you please state any solution for this ?

Comment: not sure, but can you make sure that the domains of the editor and the page where you draged the image from are on the same domain?