# Which event get triggers on image drag and drop using Tinymce .

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have some images from which some are very large images that i want to drag and drop into Tinymce editor. Now my screen size to allow for that image is 600 - 800 pixels . The image when droped in my editor expands to full screen which i don't want .

My requirement : I want to resize the image according to my dimension of 600 by 800 pixels when dropped in the editor . So is there any way to achieve this particular thing ?

Also , is it possible to edit the `uploadImages` function callback ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know about the uploadImages function callback.

You will have to add own handlers to the tinymce body that will react on drop.
something like this should work:

```
var editor = tinymce.get('your_editor_id');
$(ed.getBody()).bind('dragend', function(e){ /* your magic here */});
```

Comment: Thank you , i will try it out .

Comment: `your_editor_id` means the `div`'s id in which my tinymce is in ? right ?

Comment: the editor id is the same id as the dom element id (i.e. a textarea) for which you create the editor. In case this element does not have an id 'content' is used as editor id.

Comment: @Thariama This event is not working, when we do this from firebug console. 

`var editor = tinymce.get('content');

editor.dom.bind(editor.dom.getRoot(), 'dragend', function(e){ 
  alert("Hello");
  console.log("hello...");
})

console.log(editor);`

Comment: please try the events dragover, dragenter, drag and drop

Comment: @Thariama : I am not able to access the editor's id as the `dom.getRoot()` gives null . please let me know how to resolve this .

Comment: @Thariama : the problem with your updated answer is the log gets printed when the image is dragged and dropped inside the editor content area , not when the image is dragged from outside the editor content and then dropped in editor area. please let me know the solution for this problem.

Comment: in this case you will need to add a handler listening for the drag event to the body of the dom where you want to drag from

Comment: @Thariama : Now , i have this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442387/dragging-replacement-of-the-data/7486441#7486441 problem of Not allowing modification of document , can you please state any possible solution for this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99932/discussion-between-huzefa-biyawarwala-and-thariama).